# Почему не дочерний блок не занимает пространство родительского блока?

Tags: html, css

Не понимаю, почему контейнер со слайдами не сжимается вместе с блоком в котором он находится?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
const swiper11111 = new Swiper('.slider-cont', {
  // Optional parameters
  direction: 'horizontal',
  loop: true,
  slidesPerView: 3,
  spaceBetween: 50,
  grid: {
    rows: 2,
  },
});
```

```css
.slider-cont {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1150px;
  height: 750px;
}

.slider-slide {
  background-color: red;
  height: 350px;
}

.section__gallery-right-block {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.section__gallery {
  background-color: black;
}

.section__gallery-left-block-descr {
  color: aqua;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1600px;
}

.section__gallery-wrap {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <section class="section__gallery">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="section__gallery-wrap flex">
        <div class="section__gallery-left-block">
          <div class="section__gallery-inner-left-block">
            <h2 class="section__gallery-title title-h2 white-h2" aria-label="Секция 
      галерея">
              Галерея
            </h2>
            <h4 class="section__gallery-label-for-select" aria-label="Фильтр 
        категорий">
              Фильтр:
            </h4>
            <select name="lol" id="section__gallery-select-category" class="section__gallery-select-category">
              <option value="">Живопись</option>
              <option value="">Рисунок</option>
              <option value="">Скульптура</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="section__gallery-left-block-descr">
            <p class="section__gallery-left-block-descr">
              Вам предоставляется 10&nbsp;бесплатных скачиваний. Для увеличения количества скачиваний
              <a href="#" class="section__gallery-left-block-link">авторизуйтесь,</a> либо воспользуйтесь лицензией.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section__gallery-right-block">
          <div class="slider-cont swiper">
            <div class="slider-wrap swiper-wrapper">
              <div class="slider-slide swiper-slide gallery-slider-img-1"></div>
              <div class="slider-slide swiper-slide gallery-slider-img-2"></div>
              <div class="slider-slide swiper-slide gallery-slider-img-3"></div>
              <div class="slider-slide swiper-slide gallery-slider-img-4"></div>
              <div class="slider-slide swiper-slide gallery-slider-img-5"></div>
              <div class="slider-slide swiper-slide gallery-slider-img-6"></div>
              <div class="slider-slide swiper-slide gallery-slider-img-7"></div>
              <div class="slider-slide swiper-slide gallery-slider-img-8"></div>
              <div class="slider-slide swiper-slide gallery-slider-img-9"></div>
              <div class="slider-slide swiper-slide gallery-slider-img-10"></div>
              <div class="slider-slide swiper-slide gallery-slider-img-11"></div>
              <div class="slider-slide swiper-slide gallery-slider-img-12"></div>
              <div class="slider-slide swiper-slide gallery-slider-img-13"></div>
              <div class="slider-slide swiper-slide gallery-slider-img-14"></div>
              <div class="slider-slide swiper-slide gallery-slider-img-15"></div>
              <div class="slider-slide swiper-slide gallery-slider-img-16"></div>
              <div class="slider-slide swiper-slide gallery-slider-img-17"></div>
              <div class="slider-slide swiper-slide gallery-slider-img-18"></div>
              <div class="slider-slide swiper-slide gallery-slider-img-19"></div>
              <div class="slider-slide swiper-slide gallery-slider-img-20"></div>
              <div class="slider-slide swiper-slide gallery-slider-img-21"></div>
              <div class="slider-slide swiper-slide gallery-slider-img-22"></div>
              <div class="slider-slide swiper-slide gallery-slider-img-23"></div>
              <div class="slider-slide swiper-slide gallery-slider-img-24"></div>
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: а что у вас с шириной в этом блоке происходит "swiper-wrapper-...." ? размеры там какие то огромные задаются через js

Comment: swiper-wrapper это стандартный класс слайдера.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте

```
.section__gallery-right-block {
  min-width: 0;
}
```

```js
const swiper11111 = new Swiper('.slider-cont', {
  // Optional parameters
  direction: 'horizontal',
  loop: true,
  slidesPerView: 3,
  spaceBetween: 50,
  grid: {
    rows: 2,
  },
});
```

```css
.section__gallery-right-block {
  min-width: 0;
}

.slider-cont {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1150px;
  height: 750px;
}

.slider-slide {
  background-color: red;
  height: 350px;
}

.section__gallery-right-block {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.section__gallery {
  background-color: black;
}

.section__gallery-left-block-descr {
  color: aqua;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1600px;
}

.section__gallery-wrap {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <section class="section__gallery">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="section__gallery-wrap flex">
        <div class="section__gallery-left-block">
          <div class="section__gallery-inner-left-block">
            <h2 class="section__gallery-title title-h2 white-h2" aria-label="Секция 
      галерея">
              Галерея
            </h2>
            <h4 class="section__gallery-label-for-select" aria-label="Фильтр 
        категорий">
              Фильтр:
            </h4>
            <select name="lol" id="section__gallery-select-category" class="section__gallery-select-category">
              <option value="">Живопись</option>
              <option value="">Рисунок</option>
              <option value="">Скульптура</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="section__gallery-left-block-descr">
            <p class="section__gallery-left-block-descr">
              Вам предоставляется 10&nbsp;бесплатных скачиваний. Для увеличения количества скачиваний
              <a href="#" class="section__gallery-left-block-link">авторизуйтесь,</a> либо воспользуйтесь лицензией.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section__gallery-right-block">
          <div class="slider-cont swiper">
            <div class="slider-wrap swiper-wrapper">
              <div class="slider-slide swiper-slide gallery-slider-img-1"></div>
              <div class="slider-slide swiper-slide gallery-slider-img-2"></div>
              <div class="slider-slide swiper-slide gallery-slider-img-3"></div>
              <div class="slider-slide swiper-slide gallery-slider-img-4"></div>
              <div class="slider-slide swiper-slide gallery-slider-img-5"></div>
              <div class="slider-slide swiper-slide gallery-slider-img-6"></div>
              <div class="slider-slide swiper-slide gallery-slider-img-7"></div>
              <div class="slider-slide swiper-slide gallery-slider-img-8"></div>
              <div class="slider-slide swiper-slide gallery-slider-img-9"></div>
              <div class="slider-slide swiper-slide gallery-slider-img-10"></div>
              <div class="slider-slide swiper-slide gallery-slider-img-11"></div>
              <div class="slider-slide swiper-slide gallery-slider-img-12"></div>
              <div class="slider-slide swiper-slide gallery-slider-img-13"></div>
              <div class="slider-slide swiper-slide gallery-slider-img-14"></div>
              <div class="slider-slide swiper-slide gallery-slider-img-15"></div>
              <div class="slider-slide swiper-slide gallery-slider-img-16"></div>
              <div class="slider-slide swiper-slide gallery-slider-img-17"></div>
              <div class="slider-slide swiper-slide gallery-slider-img-18"></div>
              <div class="slider-slide swiper-slide gallery-slider-img-19"></div>
              <div class="slider-slide swiper-slide gallery-slider-img-20"></div>
              <div class="slider-slide swiper-slide gallery-slider-img-21"></div>
              <div class="slider-slide swiper-slide gallery-slider-img-22"></div>
              <div class="slider-slide swiper-slide gallery-slider-img-23"></div>
              <div class="slider-slide swiper-slide gallery-slider-img-24"></div>
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```